# Vim: Word Boundaries in Camel and Pascal Case

Tags: vim, neovim

Consider this simple Python class:

```py
class HelloFoo( ):
    def __init__( ):
        pass
```

Let's say I want to replace *Foo* in *HelloFoo* on *Bar* with <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>. But Vim recognizes *HelloFoo* as one word! How can I do it? I know I can set a cursor on *F* in *Foo* and then press <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, but this is not what I want, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim currently doesn't have a motion or text object for these (but it's been on the wish list for a long time).

You can use a plugin like my [camelcasemotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905), which provides `,w` / `,e` and `,b` motion variants of `w` / `e` / `b`, and also `i,w` etc. text objects. The plugin page has links to alternative plugins; one notable one is [vim-wordmotion](https://github.com/chaoren/vim-wordmotion); it also provides both motions and text objects, has customizable mappings and extra separator characters. Unlike most other implementations, it does not use complex regular expressions.

Comment: Nice, [vim-wordmotion](https://github.com/chaoren/vim-wordmotion) is exactly what I needed.